# Using nested CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, nested, case

I'm using SQL Server and trying the modify the below query specifically a different approach for the `case` statement.

The below query works fine and returns the correct results when the `TransactionalCurrency` is `USD`.

But I'm looking for modifications.

Say for example, for a particular MasterPolicyNumber, when the **Transactional Currency is not USD**, then I'm looking to join to another table (TransDetails) on MasterPolicyNumber and use its value of 'Renewed Layer' column to this query.  Basically copying the value of 'Renewed Layer' of TransDetails and pasting it in below results only when TransactionalCurrency is not USD.

```
            with PolicyDtls as 
            ( select 
                     MasterPolicyNumber,
                     PolicyNumber,  
                     NewRenewal,
                     TransactionalCurrency,     
                     LimitUSD, 
                     AttachmentType, 
                     ISNULL(AttachmentUSD, 0) + ISNULL(SIR_USD,0) +  ISNULL(DeductibleUSD,0)  as  AttachmentUSD     
                     from Policy_Test   
            )


            select
                   ref.Region,     
                   ref.MasterPolicyNumber,     
                   previous.MasterPolicyNumber as PriorMasterPolicyNumber,
                   curr.TransactionalCurrency, 
                   curr.LimitUSD,   
                   previous.LimitUSD as prevLimitUSD,
                   curr.AttachmentUSD,  
                   previous.AttachmentUSD as prevAttachUSD,
                   case when  curr.LimitUSD = previous.LimitUSD and curr.AttachmentUSD = previous.AttachmentUSD then 'Renewed Same Layer' 
                        when  (curr.LimitUSD <> previous.LimitUSD OR curr.AttachmentUSD <> previous.AttachmentUSD ) 
                              and previous.AttachmentUSD IS NOT NULL 
                              then 'Renewed Different Layer' 
                        else 'Renewed Unknown' 
                    end as   'Renewal Layer', 
                   curr.AttachmentType

            from Actuarial.Rptng.Renewal_XREF ref
            left join PolicyDtls curr on curr.MasterPolicyNumber = ref.MasterPolicyNumber 
            left join PolicyDtls previous on previous.MasterPolicyNumber = ref.Prior_MasterPolicyNumber
            where 
            curr.NewRenewal = 'Renewal'
            and curr.MasterPolicyNumber = '49-NPR-000013-02'
            order by curr.PolicyNumber
```

Sample Data using just the above query:

```
--===== If the test table already exists, drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#mytable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #mytable

--===== Create the test table with 
CREATE TABLE #mytable 
(
    Region nvarchar(300), 
    MasterPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
    PriorPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
    TransactionalCurrency nvarchar(100), 
    LimitUSD float,
    prevLimitUSD  float, 
    AttachmentUSD  float,
    prevAttachUSD float, 
    RenewedLayer nvarchar(300), 
    AttachmentType nvarchar(100)
)

SET DATEFORMAT DMY

--===== Insert the test data into the test table
INSERT INTO #mytable (Region, MasterPolicyNumber, PriorPolicyNumber, TransactionalCurrency, LimitUSD, prevLimitUSD, AttachmentUSD,  prevAttachUSD,  RenewedLayer,   AttachmentType)
    SELECT 'EUR', '47-ACA-000001-02', '47-ACA-000001-01', 'EUR', '7105.8', '6218.6', '32763', '23273', 'Renewed Differed Layer', 'Excess' 


    select *from #mytable
```

SAMPLE DATA of TransDetails Table

```
--===== If the test table already exists, drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TransDetails') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TransDetails

--===== Create the test table with 
CREATE TABLE #TransDetails 
(
    Region nvarchar(300), 
    MasterPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
    PriorPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
    TransactionalCurrency nvarchar(100), 
    LimitTrans float,
    prevLimitTrans  float, 
    AttachmentTrans  float,
    prevAttachTrans float, 
    RenewedLayer nvarchar(300), 
    AttachmentType nvarchar(100)
)

SET DATEFORMAT DMY

--===== Insert the test data into the test table
INSERT INTO  #TransDetails(Region, MasterPolicyNumber, PriorPolicyNumber, TransactionalCurrency, LimitTrans, prevLimitTrans, AttachmentTrans,   prevAttachTrans,    RenewedLayer,   AttachmentType)
    SELECT 'EUR', '47-ACA-000001-02', '47-ACA-000001-01', 'EUR', '8000', '8000', '3000', '3000', 'Renewed Same Layer', 'Excess' 


    select *from  #TransDetails
```

**Expected Results**

```
--===== If the test table already exists, drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#mytable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #mytable

--===== Create the test table with 
CREATE TABLE #mytable 
(
    Region nvarchar(300), 
    MasterPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
    PriorPolicyNumber nvarchar(300),
    TransactionalCurrency nvarchar(100), 
    LimitUSD float,
    prevLimitUSD  float, 
    AttachmentUSD  float,
    prevAttachUSD float, 
    RenewedLayer nvarchar(300), 
    AttachmentType nvarchar(100)
)

SET DATEFORMAT DMY

--===== Insert the test data into the test table
INSERT INTO #mytable (Region, MasterPolicyNumber, PriorPolicyNumber, TransactionalCurrency, LimitUSD, prevLimitUSD, AttachmentUSD,  prevAttachUSD,  RenewedLayer,   AttachmentType)
    SELECT 'EUR', '47-ACA-000001-02', '47-ACA-000001-01', 'EUR', '7105.8', '6218.6', '32763', '23273', 'Renewed Same Layer', 'Excess' 


    select *from #mytable
```

Comment: Not getting what is stopping you from left joining to TransDetails on MasterPolicyNumber and using TransDetails.Renewed Layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the JOIN to `TransDetail` can be made so that it does not create duplicates, you can simply add it as an OUTER JOIN in the FROM clause, and do something like this to your existing CASE expression:

```
               case 
                    when curr.TransactionalCurrency<>'USD' then TransDetail.RenewedLayer
                    when  curr.LimitUSD = previous.LimitUSD and curr.AttachmentUSD = previous.AttachmentUSD then 'Renewed Same Layer' 
                    when  (curr.LimitUSD <> previous.LimitUSD OR curr.AttachmentUSD <> previous.AttachmentUSD ) 
                          and previous.AttachmentUSD IS NOT NULL 
                          then 'Renewed Different Layer' 
                    else 'Renewed Unknown' 
                end as   'Renewal Layer',
```